# Quick way to clear Calendar invitations?

Tags: calendar, ical

For some reason, for exchange accounts, if I accept/deny calendar invitations on one computer, it would still stay as an alert on my other computers. The alert would not ask me to accept/reject, instead it would just ask me to dismiss it with an "ok" button. It's super annoying because that means I have to click "ok" for each calendar invite for each computer I have.

Is there a way to fix this or at least a quick way to dismiss all incoming event that have already been accepted?

[image]

Answer (score 43):

Hold down the <kbd>alt</kbd> key when you have the invitations list in view.

All the **OK** buttons will change to **Ok All** and all the  **Accept** buttons will change to **Accept All**

Clicking the **Ok All** will clear the invitations with just the **OK All**.

The other buttons do not change annoyingly. As I would like **Decline All**

Comment: `alt` is useful for activating 'alternative' menu items along the whole system.

Comment: @CousinCocaine , Correct. That why it was the first thing I tried. :-)

Comment: Wow, glad to find an answer to this so easily.

Comment: There are no OK buttons. There are only Maybe, Accept, and Decline buttons, and only Accept becomes "Accept all"

Comment: A lot of my notifications are for events that I've already accepted elsewhere, and are now in the past. Does this send a notification to the inviter?

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I also don't want to accept or decline all. I just want them to go away. I guess this means I'll go back to the calendar web app.

Answer (score 0):

Instantly clear notifications in calendar inbox, never get those again:

**Calendar** > **calendars**
Next to each calendar (shared/subscribed) is an “info” button. Click.

**Shared Changes**: turn off.  This will instantly clear the inbox.

**FYI**: Below the color choices is **Event Alerts**: choose on/off to get notification for the upcoming events (day before, hour before, time to leave, etc), whatever alert option was initially used when event was created.

Comment: This solution is for iOS. I believe the question refers to Calendar mac app.

Comment: On MacOS Calendar Version 14.0 (2964.2.2), I do have in information entry in the context menu, but that only seems to allow toggling event alerts. I would love to see a "shared changes" option as well.